# Embedding Basic-Script in ArcGIS?

Tags: python, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

in the Program "Grapher" from Golden Software, you're writing in a modified script-language, based on `BASIC`.
I want to run the script I wrote in ArcGIS either using a toolbox or as an arcpy interface.

How do I run the BASIC script in ArcGIS?

I'm working with ArcMap 10.3.1

I found a solution to open "Surfer"(another app from Golden Software), but not `Grapher`

```
import win32com.client 
def main(): 
    app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Surfer.Application") 
    plot = app.Documents.Add(1) 
    app.Visible = True 
main()
```

Comment: ArcGIS uses Python to *avoid* the use of custom languages.  Python is robust  enough as a language to write a BASIC interpreter, but the development of same is not a GIS task, nor is it sufficiently focused to be appropriate anywhere in the Stack family of exchanges..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subprocess` module should do the job:

```
import subprocess
# ... do what you need to do
grapher = "\path\to\grapher.exe"
x_opt = '-x'
bas_file = "\path\to\filename.bas"
result = subprocess.check_output([grapher, x_opt, bas_file])
print result
```

I'm showing `subprocess.check_output` but depending on what Grapher does you might use `subprocess.call` or other `subprocess` functions.